# .awk escape character inside regex

Tags: regex, awk, escaping

I don't quite understand how escape the character works in .awk scripts.

I have this line in the file I want to read:

```
 #Name Surname City Company State Probability Units Price Amount
```

If I just write:

```
awk < test.txt '/\#/ {print $1}'
```

in the command line, then everything is fine and the output is #Name.

However, if I try to do the same inside an .awk file the following way:

```
/\#/ {print $1};
```

I get no output for this. Also, gEdit won't recognize "\" as an escape character inside .awk for some reason.

Why is this happening and is there a workaround?

Comment: It works for me. How are you running the script when you have it in a file? Also you don't need `< test.txt` just `test.txt` will work as awk expects filenames as arguments. Also, I don't think you need to escape `#` at all.

Comment: This should work: `awk '/#/{print $1}' test.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, also you don't need to escape `#` because it is not a character of special meaning.

(`my.awk`) contents:

```
/#/ {print $1};
```

Then execute it by using the [awk](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/awk) interpreter:

```
hwnd@lsh1001:~$ awk -f my.awk test.txt
#Name
```

Answer (score 2):

`#` is not an RE meta-character so it doesn't need to be escaped in the context of an RE to have it taken literally.

I've no idea what `gEdit` is (nor do I want to so no need to explain!) so I can't help you with your question about that - maybe post another question with a `gEdit` tag so people who know that tool will look at it?

Running this on the command line:

```
awk '/\#/ {print $1}' test.txt
```

WILL produce the same output as:

```
awk -f tst.awk test.txt
```

assuming tst.awk contains:

```
/\#/ {print $1}
```

Again you do not need to escape the `#` but that's beside the point. If that's not what you are experiencing then the most likely reason is that the editor you used to create tst.awk corrupted the file somehow, maybe by adding control-Ms to the end of lines.

Finally - awk statements are terminated by newlines by default, no need to add spurious semi-colons at the end of lines and chances are you will put one somewhere you REALLY don't want it some day if you dont understand that.